# *BAD*gran_size even on live disks

Tags: boot, kernel, dmesg

I am having all kind of issues with choppy performance, slow website loading, high CPU, the fan always kicking on, high load average, and so on. I have multiple kernels installed, and regardless of which one I boot from, dmesg shows a number of *BAD*gran_size entries. I can add mtrr_cleanup and other flags to grub, and the message will go away, but performance is always buggy, still, to varying degrees.

What makes it even stranger is that a live disk shows *BAD*gran_size as well, so it can't be the way my kernels are installed. I have tried a 17.04 disk, 16.04.3, 16.04.2, 16.04 and 14.04. All show the error in dmesg.

I ran memtest a few weeks ago and there didn't appear to be anything wrong with my RAM. I am running memtester now and we'll see what happens. But if I didn't have this error before, and now it's kernel-independant, does this mean I have a hardware problem? Where do I go from here?

Comment: show me `sudo lshw -C memory`. Ping me at `@heynnema` when you have this info. Desktop or laptop?

Comment: ps: How much RAM? Also show me `cat /etc/fstab`

Comment: The bad gran size messages come from a buggy bios.  Whether they cause any harm or not is unclear.

Comment: @heynnema, lshw is here: https://pastebin.com/3Zg7rwxA; fstab here: https://pastebin.com/k2putQxY.

Comment: The lshw and fstab look ok, except the for 8G RAM, there's no swap set up. Also, have you checked for a BIOS/UEFI update at the manufacturer's web site?

Comment: OK, I just set up a swapfile, though I don't see the RAM filling up. Also, the computer used to be a windows machine and it offers bat, nsh and exe files. I'm not sure how to flash it via linux. But I do have proprietary microcode enabled, which I thought was supposed to be a way of updating CPU management without flashing the BIOS.